# Read response from callbackurl after paytm transaction in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, paytm

I am trying to integrate Paytm in an ASP.NET website.
Payment processing is going well, but when a transaction is completed, it redirects to my "callbackurl" page.

Here I don`t know how to read the response of the transaction.
I checked my callback page using inspect element but there was no json or any error message or message in console.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get status as:

```
Request.Form["Status"]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!